# Is there a good systematic approach to flying an 800 foot pattern?

Tags: traffic-pattern

I have a systematic approach to flying a 1000 foot pattern:  abeam the threshold, start a 500 fpm descent; turn when 300 feet below pattern altitude; etc.

Does anyone have a systematic approach to flying 800 foot patterns?  I'm looking for something more definite than "start a descent, don't get too low, turn on the 45, etc".

Comment: It may depend on the environment. The answer may be specific to your airport

Answer (score 1):

The trick of putting the runway half way down your wing strut visually, or a third to a half way down the wing on a low wing works great, because it automatically allows for any altitude agl being flown. As far as the rest of the pattern goes, just fly it with the same power settings and airspeed you would have in a1000 foot pattern. The base leg will get turned maybe a tiny sooner than the usual 45 degrees behind you trick, since you are starting out 200 feet lower (so you don't want to go as far away) I think it's more important that you just fly the pattern no differently...just make sure you're not out wide on downwind. The trick to consistent landings is consistent patterns and approaches. And that only comes from making sure your first circuit around is by the numbers. (i.e. airspeeds and power settings were exactly right and exactly at the proper place when they happened) Adjust accordingly after that first one, but really quiz yourself and make sure you are being consistent in the first place, before you start changing up how you do things.

Answer (score 0):

The reality of traffic pattern work is, that beyond a few basic and generic procedures, the details of flying a traffic pattern are all going to be based upon the aircraft you are flying, the airport that you are at, nearby obstacles or terrain, weather concerns, ad hoc input from ATC, etc.  A traffic pattern in a Cessna 172 at 85 KIAS is going to be quite different from that flown in a T-38 at 270 KIAS, but both use the same basic procedures.

My general approach to a VFR traffic pattern

**VFR PATTERN - single engine aircraft**

- DEPARTURE LEG from 0-400 ft AGL

  - positive rate of climb, gear up (if equipped)
- DEPARTURE LEG greater than 400 ft AGL

  - flaps up
  - set Vy and begin climb out.
  - set prop speed first then climb manifold pressure
  - clean up; boost pump off, ldg lights off, etc.
  - begin turn to crosswind leg (square pattern) or downwind leg (round pattern)
- DOWNWIND LEG

  - level out at pattern altitude for field; reduce throttle to set pattern airspeed
- THE PERCH (generally abeam threshold "piano keys")

  - Configure for landing.  Gear and flaps down, prop full, etc. GUMPS check.  Set descent airspeed.
  - Turn base or final at your discretion and/or as circumstances permit.
- FINAL APPROACH

  - Set approach speed
  - VERIFY on or above glidepath; aim for the numbers / white-red VASI, etc.
  - Final check: gear down-locked, three greens.

**VFR PATTERN - multi engine aircraft**

- DEPARTURE LEG from 0-400 ft AGL

  - positive rate of climb, gear up (if equipped)
  - accelerate while climbing to Vyse (blue line is lifeline).
- DEPARTURE LEG greater than 400 ft AGL

  - flaps up
  - set Vyse and begin climb out.
  - set prop speed first then climb manifold pressure
  - clean up; boost pump off, ldg lights off, etc.
  - begin turn to crosswind leg (square pattern) or downwind leg (round pattern)
- DOWNWIND LEG

  - level out at pattern altitude for field; reduce throttle to set pattern airspeed
- THE PERCH (generally abeam threshold "piano keys")

  - Configure for landing. Gear and flaps down, prop full, etc. GUMPS check. Set descent airspeed at Vyse (Blue line is lifeline).
  - Turn base or final at your discretion and/or as circumstances permit.
- FINAL APPROACH

  - Set final approach speed at Vyse.
  - VERIFY on or above glidepath; aim for the numbers / white-red VASI, etc.
  - Final check: gear down-locked, three greens.
  - Once you are assured you can make the runway at 1.3 Vso at round out, throttles to idle; go-around will be impossible if engine failure occurs below Vmc.  Do not attempt.

AND

**IF IT JUST DOESN'T LOOK RIGHT OR THINGS JUST ARENT LINING UP RIGHT - YOU CAN ALWAYS GO AROUND!**